# Ending up creating wrong JSON

Tags: java, json

I need to produce this JSON Object

```
{
    "Soft Drinks": {
        "T2": [
            {
                "name": "Bottled",
                "T3": [
                    {
                        "name": "Lemon",
                        "T4": [
                            {
                                "leaf": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "500 ML"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But i am always ending up with creatint this JSON

```
{
    "Soft Drinks": {
        "T2": [
            {
                "name": "Bottled",
                "T3": [
                    {
                        "name": "Lemon",
                        "leaf": [
                            {
                                "name": "500 ML"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The leaf level object should come under different obect that is T4

This is my program

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class BuildJSOn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject leaf = new JSONObject().put("name", "500 ML");

        JSONObject lemon = new JSONObject().put("name", "Lemon").put("leaf", new JSONArray().put(leaf));

        JSONArray t3Array = new JSONArray().put(lemon);


        JSONObject bottled = new JSONObject().put("name", "Bottled").put("T3", t3Array);

        JSONObject softDrink = new JSONObject().put("T2", new JSONArray().put(bottled));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject().put("Soft Drinks", softDrink);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well look at your code. Note how it doesn't mention T4 anywhere. Where do you expect that to come from?

Comment: ya , i am not sure of how to put T4 there so i left that .

Comment: Well look at how you're putting "T3". It's really unclear what the problem is here, given that you've got the rest of it... It sounds like you want an object containing a "leaf" property... and then you want to put that object into the lemon object using a "T4" property...

Comment: yes correct , i need to put the leaf under the T4 object .

Comment: So do that! Create a new object, put the "leaf" property under it, and then put that object using the T4 property. Do you understand how your existing code works? If so, I don't see what the problem is. (In fact, the T4 property should be an array containing a single object, by the looks of it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JSON structure you require, this is how your code should look.

```
JSONObject lemon = new JSONObject().put("name", "Lemon");
JSONArray t4 = new JSONArray().put(new JSONObject().put("leaf", new JSONArray().put(leaf)));
lemon.put("T4", t4);
```

Comment: I am geting a compilation error , could you please help . is it possible for you to put the whole code ?

Comment: @PreethiJain - Edited the code snippet. I had missed a little thing in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 JSONArray t4Array= new JSONArray();
        JSONArray leaf= new JSONArray();
        JSONObject newLeaf = new JSONObject().put("name", "500 ML");
        leaf.put(newLeaf);
        JSONObject t4Obj= new JSONObject().put("leaf",leaf);
        t4Array.put(t4Obj);
        JSONObject lemon = new JSONObject().put("name", "Lemon").put("T4", t4Array);

        JSONArray t3Array = new JSONArray().put(lemon);


        JSONObject bottled = new JSONObject().put("name", "Bottled").put("T3", t3Array);

        JSONObject softDrink = new JSONObject().put("T2", new JSONArray().put(bottled));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject().put("Soft Drinks", softDrink);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to mention T4 anywhere. You don't state what library you're using, or how the library you're using works (I assume you didn't write it yourself if you don't know how to add arrays to it) but I'd guess you need something like you did when adding the earlier arrays:

```
JSONArray t3Array = new JSONArray().put(lemon).put("T4", new JSONArray().put(leaf));
```

This doesn't really feel like a particularity nice solution, and that data structure looks a bit bizarre, but you need to add a `JSONArray` T4 somewhere!